# Como criar um histórico de postagens funcional?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Então, eu estava tentando criar um sistema rudimentar de "postagens" com um histórico onde todas ficariam armazenadas, porém, percebi que havia um problema o qual eu não conseguia resolver, que era o fato das postagens mais recentes serem criadas abaixo das mais antigas.

No caso, a ideia era que cada nova "postagem" sobrepusesse a anterior de forma à mais recente estar sempre no topo do histórico.

[image: Histórico de postagens]

*Exemplo do resultado visualizado no histórico*

No caso dos códigos tudo o que eu fiz foi:

**CSS**

```
    div#newDivSpace {
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        min-height: 30px;
        width: 240px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    .post {
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        padding: 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" id="userText">
    <button type="button" id="divGenerator" onclick="newDiv()">Criar div</button>
</form>
<div id="newDivSpace"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var input = document.getElementById("userText");
var button = document.getElementById("divGenerator");
var space = document.getElementById("newDivSpace");
var post = document.getElementsByClassName("post");

function newDiv() {
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        var userInput = input.value;

        if (userInput != "") {
            newDiv.innerHTML = userInput;
            newDiv.classList.add("post");
            space.appendChild(newDiv);
            input.value = "";
        }
```

Se for possível ajudar com a implementação de um sistema no qual a mensagem mais recente esteja sempre no topo do histórico sera de grande ajuda.

Comment: space.insertBefore(newDiv,someParentObject.firstChild)

Answer (score 1):

Tente utilizando o `insertBefore`

> Sintaxe

```
var elementoInserido = elementoPai.insertBefore(novoElemento, elementoDeReferencia);
```

Se **elementoDeReferencia** for null, **novoElemento** será inserido no fim da lista de nós filhos.

- **elementoInserido** - O nó sendo inserido, que é novoElemento
- **elementoPai** - Pai do nó recentemente inserido.
- **novoElemento** - O nó a ser inserido.
- **elementoDeReferencia** - O nó antes do qual o novoElemento será inserido.

> Exemplo

```
<div id="elementoPai">
  <span id="elementoFilho">foo bar</span>
</div>

<script>
// Cria um novo elemento <span> vazio
var sp1 = document.createElement("span");

// Guarda a referência do elemento atraś do qual nos queremos inserir o novo elemento
var sp2 = document.getElementById("elementoFilho");
// Guarda a referência do elemento pai
var divPai = sp2.parentNode;

// Insere o novo elemento no DOM antes de sp2
divPai.insertBefore(sp1, sp2);
</script>
```

Não existe um método insertAfter. Mas ele pode ser emulado combinando o método insertBefore com nextSibling.

No exemplo anterior, sp1 poderia ser inserido após sp2 desta forma:

> `divPai.insertBefore(sp1, sp2.nextSibling);`

Se sp2 não possuir um próximo nó, significa que ele deve ser o último filho — `sp2.nextSibling` retorna `null`, e sp1 é inserido ao fim da  da lista de nós filhos (logo após sp2).

como visto em [mozilla developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)